# Using JSON with Clojure - Undefined error

Tags: json, clojure, visual-studio-code

Hello I am trying to use Clojure to parse JSON from a website, I have read that I need to include the line

```
(require '[clojure.data.json :as json])
```

To use JSON in my program. However whenever I run this line I am getting this error

[image]

I have no idea why it won't work or if there is something else I have to include to get it work? I am planning on using slurp to consume a JSON file and parse it but cannot do it without this require (as far as i'm aware)

Any ideas?

(I am using Visual Studio Code with the Clojure extension and .lein repl to run it)

Comment: 1. You should probably be requiring using the `ns` macro. It's a little easier to use. 2. Is the `require` the the entire contents of the file?

Comment: And is that the entire error? Looks more like garbage from a "dirty" IDE.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah this is the whole file so far. what would using that entail? i'm not sure if it's a problem with visual code because in theory it should work

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with the code you posted that I can see. Try `(ns path-to-file (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))` instead; where `path-to-file` is the path to the file relative to the class path, and the name of the file. If the IDE isn't even generating that for you though, I'd get a better IDE. I use IntelliJ + Cursive (both free) and it's the best environment I've ever used for any language.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bad error msg from your IDE.

Trying creating a new dir `demo` like

```
~ > mkdir tmp-0729
~ > cd tmp-0729
~/tmp-0729 > lein new app demo
Generating a project called demo based on the 'app' template.
~/tmp-0729 > cd demo

   <add a line to project.clj in editor>

~/tmp-0729/demo > cat project.clj 
(defproject demo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
  ]
  :main ^:skip-aot demo.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

make sure you have the added requirement for `org.clojure/data.json` in `project.clj`.  Then your code should work:

```
~/tmp-0729/demo > lein repl      
nREPL server started on port 40638 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:40638
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_144-b01
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

demo.core=> (require '[clojure.data.json :as json])
nil
demo.core=> (json/write-str {:a 1 :b 2})
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"
demo.core=> (json/read-str "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}")
{"a" 1, "b" 2}
demo.core=>
```